# Sql Distinct Query

Tags: sql, distinct

I have certain fields like

```
Id
ModuleId
ModuleName
TotalAmount
Category
```

Here in my case the value of only Id and ModuleId used to change.
But I want to get whole record from this table with unique or distinct ModuleId and that too(?) the First Row which is occuring.

I tried distinct but it fails as Id's value also changes.
Very much appreciated if answered because with out this i cant go forward with my query.

Comment: It would help if you could post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Also, what flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: Soryy for not Mentioning its Sql

Comment: @Maxymus - That doesn't help! Which specific RDBMS? Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc.

Comment: @Martin - by the time they answer "it's sql" you can bet your bottom dollar it's sql (server). But then that leads to the question about version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work on most DBMS

```
select Id, ModuleId, ModuleName, TotalAmount, Category
from tbl
where id in 
(
select min(id)
from tbl
group by moduleid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate functions like sum, avg, max, min.

```
select id, ModuleId, max(modulename), avg(TotalAmount), max(Category)
from table
group by id, ModuleId
```

Comment: (only if it doesn't have to be the first row with a specific order by)

Comment: ModuleId, max(modulename) and max(Category) don't necessarily belong to the same row.  There may be no row with an actual value of avg(TotalAmount).